# Jenkins parameterize number of retry attempts in options directive

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to use a parameter in a retry block? I'm trying to parameterize the number of times the Replicate stage will retry by creating an env variable that is an int and passing it into retry like so: `retry(env.numberOfTryAttempts)` however the retry doesn't work and only runs the job once before marking as failure. I've included the pipeline below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'NUMBER_OF_TRY_ATTEMPTS', defaultValue: '3', trim: true)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.tryCount = 0
                    env.numberOfTryAttempts = Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_TRY_ATTEMPTS)
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Replicate') {
            options {
                retry(env.numberOfTryAttempts)
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    tryCount = env.tryCount as Integer
                    tryCount++
                    env.tryCount = "${tryCount}"
                    echo "Replicate try number: ${tryCount}"

                    error("Replicate Failed...")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            echo "Replicate Failed after ${tryCount} attempts"
        }
        success {
            echo "Replicate Succeeded after ${tryCount} attempts"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the parameter in a function call, you can pass the function to `retry`.
For example, if you define
`def maxAttempts = Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_TRY_ATTEMPTS)`
then you can make the retry call the function
`retry(maxAttempts)`

Comment: got it working putting the `def maxAttempts = Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_TRY_ATTEMPTS)` above the pipeline {} block thanks @Arlo !